# sage error : No module named pygments.token

Tags: python, sage

I installed sage from source into my home directory in my ubuntu-mate system, as it specified in its documentation installation from source took several hours to go through, after it i ran "sage" from terminal and it ran examples like 2+2 -> 4 correctly, sage installation seemed sucessful, but in a second session after trying to run sage from terminal it prompt this error

```
juan@juan-Satellite-C645:~$ sage
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ SageMath version 8.1, Release Date: 2017-12-07                     │
│ Type "notebook()" for the browser-based notebook interface.        │
│ Type "help()" for help.                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/sagemath/bin/sage-ipython", line 7, in <module>
    from sage.repl.interpreter import SageTerminalApp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sage/repl/interpreter.py", line 108, in <module>
    from sage.repl.prompts import SagePrompts, InterfacePrompts
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sage/repl/prompts.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pygments.token import Token
ImportError: No module named pygments.token
```

Comment: I'm curious: if you're building from source, why build a version that is more than 2 years old? Try SageMath 9.1 instead. In more detail, unpack the tarball, run `./configure` and see what hints it gives at the end for system packages to install. Follow the hints, then run `make`.

Comment: Hi Juan, 

As @JohnPalmieri suggests, the version you're building is more than 2 years old. Could you try downloading the latest source code for Sage instead? Alternatively would it be easier for you to install Sage using your package manager (i.e, `apt`)?

If you still want to move forward with what yu have, could you try installing `pygments` manually? --> `pip2 install --user pygments` and rerun your executable?